# persisting filters in grid panel

Tags: extjs

I would like to persist filters applied on gridpanel on page refresh. Can you please guide me in doing this.

Thanks.

---

Here is the code which send the filter data to webservice

```
 Ext.extend(Ext.ux.AspWebServiceProxy, Ext.data.DataProxy,       
 {
  load: function(params, reader, callback, scope, arg) {                 
  var userContext = {
               callback: callback,                   
               reader: reader,
               arg: arg,
               scope: scope
           };

  var proxyWrapper = this;

           //debugger;
           //Handles the response we get back from the web service call
           var webServiceCallback = function(response, context, methodName) {
               proxyWrapper.loadResponse(response, userContext, methodName);
           }

           var serviceParams = [];
           var filters = {};
           //Convert the params into an array of values so that they can be used in the call (note assumes that the properties on the object are in the correct order)
           for (var property in params) {
               if (property.indexOf("filter[") == 0) {
                   filters[property] = params[property];
               }
               else {
                   serviceParams.push(params[property]);
               }
               //console.log("Property: ", property, "Value: ", params[property]);
           }
           serviceParams.push(filters);

           //Add the webservice callback handlers
           serviceParams.push(webServiceCallback);
           serviceParams.push(this.handleErrorResponse);

           //Make the actual ASP.Net web service call
           this.webServiceProxyMethod.apply(this.webServiceProxy, serviceParams);
       },

       handleErrorResponse: function(response, userContext, methodName) {
           window.location.reload();
           //                               Ext.MessageBox.show({
           //                                       title: 'Error',
           //                                       msg: response.get_message(),
           //                                       buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
           //                                       icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
           //                                   });
           //alert("Error while calling method: " + methodName + "n" + response.get_message());
       },

       loadResponse: function(response, userContext, methodName) {
           var result = userContext.reader.readRecords(response);
           userContext.callback.call(userContext.scope, result, userContext.arg, true);
       }

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Ext JS state manager globally (where you set `Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL`).

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
```

User changes to some components will now be stored in a cookie, which will persist across requests. If you need to store additional custom data, you can do that using `Ext.state.Manager.set` and `Ext.state.Manager.get`. State is configurable on individual components.

Saki has a [good example](http://examples.extjs.eu/).

Comment: Ext state manger is turned on .the problem is grid panel shows that filters is checked and the data inside it (textbox) is also persisted but the problem is i dont see the filtered grid when i clcik refresh. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: You might need to manually reload the store when the state is restored. Post some code so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Hi..

The value of the filter textbox is stored in cookie(read cookie in ext-all-debug.js).But when page reloads getfilterdata and buildquery in beforeload are not being called. The beforeload function of gridfilters.js is not being called when page is refreshed.can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

To persist filters on grid you can use cookies, here you can find some help:

```
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: (local ? url.local : url.remote),
        method: 'GET',
        listeners:{
            beforeload : function(dataproxy,param) {
                if(param.searchConditions != undefined && param.searchConditions != '[]') {                     
                    Ext.util.Cookies.set('SearchConditions',param.searchConditions);
                }

            }
        }
    })
```

In above sample you can find that we are setting "searchConditions" JSONArray in cookies.Now let us see how to get back that "searchCondition" whenever you load you Grid.

```
store.load({
            params:{
                start:0,
                limit: 50,
                searchConditions:JSON.parse(Ext.util.Cookies.get('SearchConditions'));
            }
        });
```

Here simply you just need to pass your "searchCondition" parameter value as value stored in Cookie. Hope above example is useful.Please comment for any help.